# How to make an R script callable so that I can generate a figure/file from the command line?

Tags: r, linux

I want to be able to generate the figure and csv file from the linux command line by calling the Rscript. As an example, `testing.R` has the following:

```
input <- mtcars[,c('mpg','cyl')]

write.table(input, "mtcars.csv")

pdf("boxplot.pdf")
boxplot(mpg ~ cyl, data = mtcars, xlab = "Number of Cylinders",
        ylab = "Miles Per Gallon", main = "Mileage Data")
dev.off()
```

When I called `testing.R`, I only get "null device". Are my plot and csv file generated?

```
Rscript testing.R mtcars.csv boxplot.pdf

null device 
          1
```

Answer (score 1):

Your plot and your CSV file - you should use `write.csv`, by the way - are being written to disk but to your home directory. Try printing the working directory, include the following as your first instruction:

```
print(getwd())
```

The result is now

```
C:\Users\ruipb\Documents\so_temp>Rscript testing.R
[1] "C:/Users/ruipb/Documents"
null device
          1

C:\Users\ruipb\Documents\so_temp>
```

And the command line arguments `mtcars.csv boxplot.pdf` are not being used.